# Null safelty Flutter causing late initialiation error

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, bluetooth, mobile-application

I am building a flutter app to communicate via bluetooth. When the app is connecting to the other end I get this error for few seconds on the screen until the connection is established then it goes away whish is like this:

**On a red screen: LateInitializationError: Field 'connection' has not been initialized.**

I think what is causing this error is this line:

```
late BluetoothConnection connection ;
```

But if I remove the late then I get an error because of the null safety. I tried to disable the null safety on the whole project but the error didnt stopp.

I also tried to make it nullable :

```
BluetoothConnection? connection ;
```

but then i get other errors in other properties depending on it : **The property 'isConnected' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.**

```
  bool get isConnected => connection.isConnected;
```

Comment: have you tried initializing a new variable like this `BluetoothConnection connection = new BluetoothConnection();` ?

Comment: Read [Understanding Null Safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety).  Don't use `late` unless you can *guarantee* the variable will not be accessed before being initialized.  If you need to check if it's been initialized, use a nullable variable, and check if it's null.

Comment: @Danny Yes, but I got this error: The class 'BluetoothConnection' doesn't have an unnamed constructor.

Comment: @Danny I think I figured it out, I will post the solution once i get it done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who had similar issue, here is how I solved it:
First I changed the declaration form to:

```
BluetoothConnection? connection ;

  bool isConnecting = true;

 bool get isConnected => (connection?.isConnected ?? false);

  bool isDisconnecting = false;
```

To make BluetoothConnection nullable and then I added some changes to the rest of the code  to solve the errors I got.
Previous code:

```
connection.input?.listen
```

New code:

```
connection!.input!.listen
```

Thanks to @jameslin